# The resolvent kernel

Tags: linear-transformations, integral-equations, integral-transforms

Good morning.
How can we prove that

$$ \Gamma (s,t, \Lambda ) - \Gamma (s,t, M ) = \Lambda - M \times \int { \Gamma(s,t, \Lambda ) \times \Gamma (s,t,M) \, dx }$$

I tried to use the formula of resolvent kernel $$ \Gamma (s, t,\Lambda)  = \sum_{m=1}^\infty \Lambda ^{m-1} \times  k_m ( s,  t, \Lambda ) $$
Where  $$  k (s,t ,\Lambda ) $$ is the kernel function with the variables s and t 
and the eigenvalues are $$ \Lambda  and  M $$

Comment: Could you fix the expression ?

Comment: I tried but couldn't

Comment: I think that **\Mu** could just be **M**

Comment: Is there any answer?!

Comment: It might help if you clarify the meaning of all the symbols you're using

Comment: Is it clear now?